# Error System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies as data in ListBox in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I have ListBox, which have to display data from entity framework code first database. So my code for this task:

```
    <ListBox Grid.Column="0"
             ItemsSource="{Binding PersonCollection}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding ThePerson, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:EmployeeViewModel}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Padding="2">
                         <TextBlock.Text>
                               <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0} {1} {2}">
                                <Binding Path="ThePerson.Surname"/>
                                <Binding Path="ThePerson.FirstName"/>
                                <Binding Path="ThePerson.MidleName"/>
                            </MultiBinding>                                 
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources> 
    </ListBox>
```

My ViewModel looks like:

```
  public  EmployeeViewModel()
      {           
          ThePerson = new Person();
          _perlog = new PersonLogic();
        PersonCollection = new ObservableCollection<Person>(_perlog.Get());
      }
```

Where the ThePerson and PersonCollection have OnThePropertyChanged()
Code in PesonLogic for displaying data from table:

```
    internal IEnumerable<Person> Get()
    {
        return _dbContext.Persons.ToList();
    }
```

All this code through Error System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies. 
Can you help with solution? What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the folowing code:
`<ItemsControl.Resources>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:EmployeeViewModel}">`

To 
`<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>`

DataType="{x:Type vm:EmployeeViewModel}"> Should be written in code behind